# Add decimal number to Date - C#

Tags: c#, datetime, decimal

How to convert a decimal number (e.g. `2.5`) to year and month (2 years and 6 months) and add it to a given date? I tried `DateTime.TryParse` and it didn't work.

Comment: can u post a full example reg what u need to achieve?

Comment: There is a possibility that decimal number will result in something like `2 years, 5 months, 10 days, 11 hours...`. So, there is no direct way to resolve this. You can in turn create a function that does this calculation yourself, and then add it using TimeSpan method.

Comment: I agree with @jitendragarg. Shon's answer is good based your input but there is no _perfect_ solution for general. Even casting to `int` _might_ generate same results for different inputs like `2.5` and `2.51`. Both will generate 2 years and 6 months but second one is little bit more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decimal x =(decimal)2.5;

int nbYear = Convert.ToInt16(x);
var y = x - Math.Truncate(x);

int nbMonth =Convert.ToInt16 (y*12);
// MessageBox .Show (string.Format (" {0} years and {1} months ",nbYear ,nbMonth ));
DateTime dat=DateTime .Now ;  // or    given date
DateTime dat2 = dat.AddYears(nbYear).AddMonths(nbMonth);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using it for years then multiply the float you have by 12. 2.5 becomes 30months. Then use the addmonths function.  If I enter 5 then it will add 60 months which is 5 years

Answer (score 2):

If you init date is `dt` than

```
dt = dt.AddMonths((int)(2.5*12));
```

Comment: `AddMonths` only takes `int`

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer - thanks, changed. Though it must be checked anywhere before that the input gives correct number of months. Eg 2.4 gives 5 or 6 months?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you could just add a `TimeSpan` or use one of the `Add` methods, like this:

```
decimal yearsToAdd = (decimal)2.5;

int years = (int)Math.Floor(yearsToAdd);
decimal months = yearsToAdd - years;
int actualMonths = (int) Math.Floor(months * 12); // or Ceiling or Round

DateTime x = DateTime.Now.AddYears(years).AddMonths(actualMonths);
```

The problem is, that when you decimal doesn't yield an exacat number of months, how would you know how long e.g. half a month is? 
`28.0 / 2`, `29.0 / 2`, `30.0 / 2` or `31.0 / 2`? 
Would you take the length of the month you started with or one of the possible two months you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

If month is your smallest unit then the solution is, as pointed by many, to multiply number by 12. A more accurate alternative would be to use ticks.

```
decimal years=3.14592M; // No idea where this came from.
long ticks = (long)(356.0M * (decimal)TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * years); 
DateTime futureDate=DateTime.Today.AddTicks(ticks);
```

Note that solution will not compensate for leap years. It is not difficult to extend it - you need to calculate number of leap years in the period and use average instead of 356.0M to calculate ticks per year (i.e. avg. number of days per year * ticks per day).